# What holomorphic functions satisfy these conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

1) $|f(z)|<= |z|^k$ for all $z$ in Complex plane?

2) Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial. What holomorphic functions satisfy $|f(z)| \leq |p(z)|$ for all z in complex plane?

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, share your work and thoughts on these problems.

Comment: Hint: try k=1 for 1) and p(z)=z(z+1) for 2).

Comment: if k = 1 then we are looking at constant functions? But does the question want something that works for all k? I'm confused at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:  Modify the proof of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis) using the Cauchy integral formula for the $k'th$ (or maybe $k-1$'th derivative of $f$

Upon review, looks like you can do it with just the same formula:

Lets see:  On a circle of radius r, mimicking the proof, we have We have $$|a_n|=|\frac 1 {2\pi i}\oint _{C_r}\frac {f(\zeta)}{\zeta ^{n+1}}d\zeta |\le \frac 1 {2\pi }\oint _{C_r}|\frac {f(\zeta)}{\zeta ^{n+1}}d\zeta|\le \frac 1 {2\pi }\oint _{C_r}\frac {|z|^k}{ r^{n+1}}|d\zeta|= \frac 1 {2\pi }\oint _{C_r}\frac {r^k}{ r^{n+1}}|d\zeta|=\frac {r^k}{2\pi r^{n+1}}\oint _{C_r}|d\zeta|=\frac {r^k}{2\pi r^{n+1}}\cdot 2\pi r=\frac {r^k}{r^n} $$

Hence, if $n>k$, we have that as we take the limit as $r\to \infty$, since it works on arbitrary circles, $a_n=0$. Since an entire function can be written as a power series, and all the terms past $k$ must be zero, the only entire functions bounded by $|z^k|$ are polynomials of degree no more than $k$

Part 2 follows pretty clearly from part 1, same basic principle

Comment: I'm attempting to but I seem to be stuck. Could you possibly give me another hint? Thank you!

Comment: @j.bant Worked out part 1,  using the original formula actually (Did it with the kth' derivative to help out some undergrads earlier, but turns out to not be needed here!)